# Compiling JUnit via command line

Tags: command-line, junit, compilation, terminal, command

I know this question has been asked a couple of times before but I tried every solution and it doesn't work for me. This is my first time using JUnit and hence my inexperience with compiling test files. I am on Windows 7 64-bit and also have to test on Linux later, but I am stuck...

So I pulled out the /src folder from my Eclipse project and put the 2 jar files junit-4.11-javadoc.jar and hamcrest-core-1.3-javadoc.jar(I just guessed on the fact that I am supposed to use the javadoc jar files because I have javadoc comments present in my java files/classes) in the folder and then in command-line I navigate to the folder and then try to compile using the following command:

javac -cp .;junit-4.11-javadoc.jar Coin.java TestCoin.java

But I get a huge error message stating that package org.junit does not exist and follow by 
stating stuff like @Test cannot find symbol

How do I fix this? Eventually I need to make a make file for quick compiling for Linux, but for now I am jsut trying to get the commands for compiling via command-line/terminal.
Also, am I supposed to compile the class that I am testing too, or just the test class? In this case, Coin.java along with the TestCoin.java? 
Thanks!

Comment: As you might imagine, junit-4.11-javadoc.jar is the JAR that contains the Javadocs, not the class files.  You need to find junit-4.11.jar (etc.)

Comment: Oh ok! I actually was using the plain jar files before and it kept giving the "hamcrest not found" error

Comment: Ok so it compiles with regular jar files which I was able to before. but cannot run them. How do I do that?

Comment: `java -cp a.jar;b.jar;path/to/class/files MainClass`

Comment: I use the command java -cp .;junit-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestCoin    and it gives me the ClassNotFound error for hamcrest

Comment: OMG! It works all of a sudden now! After freakin' 2 hours...I believe the problem was I had to compile all the files in the folder. I will have to verify that, but whatever, it works!